# Change permission in phonegap build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, build

I was trying to test the camera/fileupload features of phonegap and was compiling the example app right from their docs in phonegap build. However, I'm realizing that because of permissions i am not successful. How would I add permissions for camera/fileupload in a phonegap build project? I notice you have to add a config.xml file but what about the androidmanifest? I really am new to this and can't find a good example.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the top of your manifest file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

Comment: Could you give me a manifest template? I do not have to begin with as im only using build atm..Also will that take care of filetransfers?

Comment: Yes it should..
Manifest Template:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: It looks like you can't supply the androidmanifest.xml for phonegap build. Looks like I will have to use Eclipse.. thanks anyway

Comment: The permissions are OK but you also need to add the Cordova plugins